# Proof of Binet's formula continued fraction

Tags: analysis, fibonacci-numbers, continued-fractions

This is the question 4(h), 3.1.5, Mathematical Analysis I by Zorich.

In part (g), I was given that
$$
\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\ldots}},
$$
and I think I should use this to prove the Binet's formula
$$
u_{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}\right].
$$

How can I solve it? It is okay to just give a hint so that I can work out myself.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit wouldn't it be $x^2 - x - 1 = 0$?

Comment: the expression $1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\ldots}}$ need some context to be well-defined, you must understand it as the limit of the sequence $1,1+\frac1{1},1+\frac1{1+\frac1{1}},\ldots $